# Using a button as a link (GET request)

Tags: html, asp.net, css, webforms

Is it possible to use a button as a link in ASP.NET? I am aware that `Response.Redirect` can be used in the button's `OnClick` handler, but that would cause two trips (a POST and a GET) to the server instead of one, and I'd like to avoid that if I can.

If that's not possible, then how can I disguise my link as a button, and has the 'pressed-in' effect when clicked? I tried wrapping a link within a button, and setting appropriate CSS styles such as `text-decoration:none` to the link, but the link only works when I click on the text within the button, not the entire button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I know is to use `location.href` property in `OnClientClick` event of button.

**See following example:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
OnClientClick="window.location.href='your edit URL here'" />
```